# What is the issue with my wamp server

Tags: wamp

```
Internal Server Error  
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.  Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
```

More infortion.

After i went through the log file i found this but i dont know how to debug it

```
[Wed Sep 24 12:29:50.808777 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7716:tid 304] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Sep 24 12:29:53.569982 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6836:tid 388] AH00430: Parent: Child process 7716 exited successfully.
[Wed Sep 24 12:38:59.563516 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4612:tid 388] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Sep 24 12:38:59.598518 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4612:tid 388] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Wed Sep 24 12:38:59.598518 2014] [core:notice] [pid 4612:tid 388] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Wed Sep 24 12:38:59.600518 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4612:tid 388] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5232
[Wed Sep 24 12:39:00.554573 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5232:tid 304] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Sep 24 20:59:56.118653 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4612:tid 388] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Sep 24 20:59:58.571793 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5232:tid 304] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Sep 24 21:00:23.437495 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4612:tid 388] AH00430: Parent: Child process 5232 exited successfully.
[Thu Sep 25 08:41:53.157396 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1032:tid 392] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 25 08:41:53.166397 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1032:tid 392] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Thu Sep 25 08:41:53.166397 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1032:tid 392] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Thu Sep 25 08:41:53.168397 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1032:tid 392] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6796
[Thu Sep 25 08:41:55.282518 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6796:tid 316] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Sep 25 10:46:27.453901 2014] [core:error] [pid 6796:tid 836] [client 127.0.0.1:4242] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Thu Sep 25 10:47:56.015967 2014] [core:error] [pid 6796:tid 844] [client 127.0.0.1:4282] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Thu Sep 25 10:53:11.816030 2014] [core:error] [pid 6796:tid 832] [client 127.0.0.1:4443] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Thu Sep 25 10:55:26.231718 2014] [core:error] [pid 6796:tid 852] [client 127.0.0.1:4476] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Comment: Please show your .htaccess and/or your Virtual Host definitions. Also what have you changed from the initial installation state.

Answer (score 0):

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

In combination with the the 500 (internal server) error message, it kind of sounds like you have a problem with the `RedirectRule` lines in your .htaccess file, that keep on redirecting the request in a loop.